# Simplest way to replace AD with ADFS (or add it on top it)?

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory, adfs, azure-blockchain-workbench

I have a client app and it is a single-tenant app in AD. What I actually need is a collaboration between a couple of AD users in order to share our users (all users will eventually be used in 1 shared resource which is the blockchain workbench). I have come to realize that my use case requires ADFS. In every tutorial I encounter I see that it require setting up a lot of new servers. Isn't there a simple way to add the Federation services into my use case?

Comment: When you say "or add it on top it" in the title.. if you're looking to configure federation with on-premises ADFS.. then take a look at Azure AD Connect.. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-fed-whatis

Comment: I have wrote on top of it as I am a beginner in Azure. I wrote it as I am not entirely sure if I am replacing AD with ADFS or not. My end target is to have a federation with a couple of AD users so we can share our users inside a resources but for each tenant to manage their own user.

Comment: ok, if your end target is federation.. then Azure AD Connect should make sense.. give it a read.. you will not be replacing Azure AD, but enabling federation with ADFS in that case.. Also note that Azure AD and Active Directory (AD) are separate products.. so when you mention having "a single-tenant app in AD".. it's probably Azure AD